# Getting SharePoint project to work in Visual Studio 2010 without installing SP on workstation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am doing some maintenance on a set of systems including a SharePoint 2010 site. There is a Visual Studio 2010 solution containing some SharePoint projects that I need to be able to build and deploy.

My developer workstation has a basic setup with Visual Studio 2010 Professional on Windows 7.

Unsurprisingly, all references in this project to the various SharePoint assemblies (Microsoft.SharePoint, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing etc.) are all broken and prevent me from building and deploying the project.

The Microsoft developer resources that I've found outline a tortuously involved process of preparing the workstation with various prerequisites, then installing SharePoint while jumping through various hoops - described in some lengthy getting started documents that are, quite frankly, far beyond the scope of the task at hand.

Right now, all I need to do is make some minor corrections, build the project and deploy the updated assemblies and files to the server. I have no need at this point of integrated debugging, template design, site definitions or any of that stuff.

Is there a way to simply install the necessary SharePoint assemblies so that the project will build?

Please?

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy sharepoint dlls from your servers `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\` folder to local machine and register them to the **GAC**.

[Source](http://www.techerator.com/2011/02/how-to-perform-sharepoint-development-on-a-client-workstation/)